# Snowflake null value - Is possible to replace a null value to a VARCHAR value?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query that gives me a null value result, however, I am starting the stuff with dashboards and I am creating KPIs, I would like to replace the null value with a VARCHAR value, is this possible?

Thank you.

I am trying to find information but I am not sure on how to elaborate the query to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IFNULL function: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ifnull.html

```
SELECT IFNULL( null, 'THIS WAS NULL' );
```